# Where is the correct place to initialize the DRb service within a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backgroundrb, drb

I'm using DRb within a Rails application to offload an expensive task outside the Rails process. Before initializing the client stub with DRbObject.new it is necessary to initialize the DRb service with DRb.start_service.

Doing this in model or controller appears to leave threads in an uncertain state. When I exit mongrel it says:

`Reaping 1 threads for slow workers because of 'shutdown'
Waiting for 1 requests to finish, could take 60 seconds.`

Initializing the service in environment.rb seems to work fine with a big caveat: I'm also using backgroundrb with some rails workers. When they initialize they run environment.rb and again lead to issues due to double-initialization.

Where is the correct place to call DRb.start_service in the client? Or, is there a way to test for initialization so I can avoid doing it twice for the same process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will check if a primary server is already active  to avoid double initialization. The mongrel hang on exit can be avoided by moving the DRb thread to a ThreadGroup different from the one mongrel is using.

```
    # start DRb service if it hasn't been started before
    begin
        DRb.current_server
    rescue DRb::DRbServerNotFound
        DRb.start_service
        # move to different ThreadGroup to avoid mongrel hang on exit
        ThreadGroup.new.add DRb.thread
    end
```

Running this before the class is used (rather than in environment.rb) yielded the best results and seems to work fine with backgroundrb.